# Замена src у video, которое рисуется в canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, видео

Есть `canvas`, который рисует `video`. Я хочу поменять источник видео и пока делаю это просто изменением атрибута `src`. Я не понимаю, что в таком случае происходит с канвасом, но при каждой смене источника (или `load` у видео) 
 производительность падает, а нагрузка на CPU растет. Очевидно, делаю что-то не правильно.

Собственно, вопрос - почему так происходит и как правильно менять источник видео, чтобы избежать возможных проблем с производительностью?

P.S В сниппете канвас маленький, лагать начинает после 30+ замен, в проекте канвас на весь экран и их две штуки, там это заметно уже после 6-8 замены.

```js
videos = new Array();

videos[0] = {
  source: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"
};
videos[1] = {
  source: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4"
};
videos[2] = {
  source: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4"
};

var setSource = function(num) {
  $('video').attr('src', videos[num].source);
}

var loadVideo = function() {
  var i = 0;
  var loadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    i += 1;
    $('video').get(0).load();
    if (i == 41) {
      clearInterval(loadTimer);
    };
  }, 100);
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  function step() {
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
})

let frameCount = function _fc(timeStart) {
  let now = performance.now();
  let duration = now - timeStart;
  if (duration < 1000) {
    _fc.counter++;
  } else {
    _fc.fps = _fc.counter;
    _fc.counter = 0;
    timeStart = now;
    $("#fps-counter").html(_fc.fps);
    if (_fc.fps >= 55) {
      $("#fps-counter").css("color", "green");
    } else if (_fc.fps >= 30) {
      $("#fps-counter").css("color", "orange");
    } else if (_fc.fps < 30) {
      $("#fps-counter").css("color", "red");
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(() => frameCount(timeStart));
};

frameCount.counter = 0;
frameCount.fps = 0;
frameCount(performance.now());
```

```css
canvas, video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

canvas {
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

video {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Set video source</p>
<button onclick="setSource(0)">1</button>
<button onclick="setSource(1)">2</button>
<button onclick="setSource(2)">3</button>
<p>video.load() x40</p>
<button onclick="loadVideo()">load()</button>
<p> fps: <span id='fps-counter'>0</span></p>

<video autoplay muted loop src='https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4'></video>

<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: А у меня видео в канвасе совсем не показывает(

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Вроде опера не рисует канвас, если видео не отображается. А сейчас попробуйте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в событии `play`. При каждой смене источника или загрузке это событие вызывается.
Соответственно, у вас очень много одинаковых вызовов функции `step`. Из-за этого и происходит утечка.

Способ решения в примере - просто proof of concept. В реальном коде надо будет сделать как-то по другому.

```js
videos = new Array();

videos[0] = {
  source: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"
};
videos[1] = {
  source: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4"
};
videos[2] = {
  source: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4"
};

var setSource = function(num) {
  $('video').attr('src', videos[num].source);
}

var loadVideo = function() {
  var i = 0;
  var loadTimer = setInterval(function() {
    i += 1;
    $('video').get(0).load();
    if (i == 41) {
      clearInterval(loadTimer);
    };
  }, 100);
}

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const video = document.querySelector('video');
let isPlaying = false;
video.addEventListener('play', () => {
  if (!isPlaying) {
    console.log('play');
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
    isPlaying = true;
  }
});

function step() {
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}


let frameCount = function _fc(timeStart) {
  let now = performance.now();
  let duration = now - timeStart;
  if (duration < 1000) {
    _fc.counter++;
  } else {
    _fc.fps = _fc.counter;
    _fc.counter = 0;
    timeStart = now;
    $("#fps-counter").html(_fc.fps);
    if (_fc.fps >= 55) {
      $("#fps-counter").css("color", "green");
    } else if (_fc.fps >= 30) {
      $("#fps-counter").css("color", "orange");
    } else if (_fc.fps < 30) {
      $("#fps-counter").css("color", "red");
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(() => frameCount(timeStart));
};

frameCount.counter = 0;
frameCount.fps = 0;
frameCount(performance.now());
```

```css
canvas,
video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

canvas {
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

video {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Set video source</p>
<button onclick="setSource(0)">1</button>
<button onclick="setSource(1)">2</button>
<button onclick="setSource(2)">3</button>
<p>video.load() x40</p>
<button onclick="loadVideo()">load()</button>
<p> fps: <span id='fps-counter'>0</span></p>

<video autoplay muted loop src='https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4'></video>

<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь хоть понимаю в чем причина. А чем этот способ плох? По какому принципу вообще мне это исправлять?

Comment: Способ плох тем, что это не способ. Что бы понять, как исправить, надо смотреть на реальный код. А также функционал, который вам нужен. Глобально - надо написать две функции, одна будет запускать цикл `requestAnimationFrame`, с проверкой, что уже цикл запущен, вторая останавливать.